# Rails 3.1 has_many :through form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have models like the following:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :registration, :uniqueness => true
  belongs_to :breed
  has_many :shows, :through => :show_entries
  has_many :show_entries
end

class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  has_many :dogs, :through => :show_entries
  has_many :show_entries
  after_save :update_event
end

class ShowEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :dog
  belongs_to :entry_class
  #DB has a bunch of other fields
end
```

I now have a form which displays a bunch of checkboxes:

```
<% for show in @shows %>
    <%= check_box_tag "dog[show_ids][]", show.id, @dog.shows.include?(show), {:id => "dogs_show_"}%>
    <%= show.name %>
<% end %>
```

I can't quite figure out what to do in the POST controller action though. How do I grab the values and update the ShowEntry table to either create or delete?

Thanks,
D.

UPDATE: I forgot to mention the ShowEntry table also has other string fields. How do I represent them in the form, and process them in the POST controller action?

Here's the form I had in mind (in pseudo HTML), assuming I have 3 Shows I can potentially associate to a Dog:

```
<div>
  check_box for Show1
  dropdownlist for entry_class
  input text for property1
  input text for property2
</div>
<div>
  check_box for Show2
  dropdownlist for entry_class
  input text for property1
  input text for property2
</div>
<div>
  check_box for Show3
  dropdownlist for entry_class
  input text for property1
  input text for property2
</div>
```

It will be styled nicely of course, with the last four lines in each  hidden or shown depending on the checked status of each check_box.

Comment: When you say POST action do you mean you are creating a new Dog? Does the extra info on the ShowEntry model come from this form or somewhere else?

Comment: The Dog record already exists, the Show records already exist too - this form is just to maintain the creation/deletion/update of the ShowEntry records.

Comment: And you can create multiple show entry records from the same form? Do they all share the extra data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right it looks like you need 'accepts_nested_attributes_for :show_entries' on the Dog model. Then in the form you need 'dog[show_entry][some unique int][some attribute name]' for each show entry/attribute combo. The unique int is used to group attributes together. It is not related to the id of the show entry model.

Then you should be able to say 'Dog.new params[:dog]' in the create action and it should automatically build out the show entries and the associations.

**UPDATE:** Sorry I was on my phone last night so it was hard to write a bunch of code. But the basic idea is to get properly formatted ShowEntry data inside the Dog form.

```
<%= form_for @dog do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :show_entries do |se_form| %>
     <%# Build form elements for existing show entries %>  
  <% end %>
  <%# These shows should either be pre-filtered down to the ones not already associated to the dog or you should add that check in the loop below %>
  <% @shows.each do |show| %>
    <%= form.fields_for :show_entries, ShowEntry.new(:show => show, :dog => @dog) do |new_se| %>
      <%# Build form elements for new show entries %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will let you create new ShowEntry records when you update the dog record. You should be able to pass `params[:dog]` directly to `update_attributes` inside your controller action.

If you want to be able to destroy the show entries also then you need to add `:allow_destroy => true` to the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` declaration. Then by passing an input named `:_destroy` with a true value for a specific `ShowEntry` in the form `update_attributes` will automatically remove the `ShowEntry` model.

You will probably want to use `:_destroy` as a hidden field set to true followed by a checkbox set to false. That way when the checkbox is checked, the record will not be destroyed and the new data will take effect. When the checkbox is unchecked `:_destroy` will be true and the record will be destroyed or not saved to the DB. You could use JavaScript to enable and disable the form fields associated to the `ShowEntry` to keep users from entering data that will not be saved.

Comment: That sounds promising. It seems you're implying this form is nested within the Dog form, is that right? I don't want this form to alter the dog record or even show it. The Show records are also existing and I don't want to alter or show them. I just want to maintain the ShowEntry records related to the Dog and Show records. I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Yes this should allow you to do that. You would do a form_for on the Dog model and then do fields_for on the existing show_entries. You will have to be a little more creative to setup the form elements for the shows that don't already have a show_entry.

Comment: I have added a bit more info in the question about the form I had in mind.

Comment: Check out this rails guide for more details. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

Comment: Thank you - I've had a look at that guide article and used it in other places. I guess I'm a bit confused about setting up a single form for a bunch of records, in this case a bunch of ShowEntry records representing the Show records available to the Dog.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I will look further into the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` declaration and give it a try this week.

Comment: Now that I look at this snippet, this will be handled by the DogController, right? I'm trying to figure out how to adapt this form to just display the Dog fields, and not update the Dog record.

Comment: If you display the Dog information inside of a `<p>` or `<div>` instead of an `<input>` it will not show up in `params` within the update action and `update_attributes` will not change those values for the Dog.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish create the association between dogs and shows then in controller.

```
dog = Dog.find(params[:id])    
dog.show_ids =  params(dog[show_ids]) # where show_ids is the array of show_ids
dog.save #I think this is optional,
```

Comment: That kinda makes sense now that I think about it. I will try later. However, I forgot to mention something about the ShowEntry table. Will update the question.

Comment: what other fields do you have?. You are creating an join entry while establishing a relationship between dog and shows. The advantage of has_many:thorough is that you’re able to add validations, callbacks, and extra attributes on the join model. I would suggest you to try to add call_back to update additional attribiutes – naren just now

Comment: Take a look at the ShowEntry model - it has one lookup field there, called entry_class. It also has two other string fields. I want to show these in the form, and persist them in the DB.

Comment: In this case when you post you need to pass not just the ids but also entry_class_id, property1, property2 along with show_id. As you see entry_class and properties does not have association to dogs or show, you need to pass adiitional input fields something like  dogs[show_id][1][entry_id], dogs[show_id][1][property1], dogs[show_id][1][property2]. Use javascript to show only entry_class, properties when a particular show is checked. Now in the model have a callback to upadte entry_class, propert1, property2 once join record is created.